# Jquery or HTML5 for an interactive map?

Tags: jquery, dictionary, html5-canvas

I would like to create a zoomable interactive map like this here http://www.greekpropertyexchange.com/

What is best to use,Jquery or HTML5 and why?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The example you have shown is Flash. You can also use SVG, Canvas or something like that. HTML5 and jQuery simply sound like buzzwords in this case.

Comment: That's right,I don't want to use flash...

Answer (score 2):

I'd use OpenLayers, a javascript mapping library. You can then either have a fully smoothly zoom and pan map (like google maps, but Free) or have the same behaviour as that site with the user clicking on a region to do that zoom to the new region.

I don't know if it uses jQuery or HTML5 or Canvas or what. I just know it works. Check out the examples on http://www.openlayers.org/ - some Javascript skills will be required to put together an application like that though.

Answer (score 0):

I would use both, because jQuery without HTML would not provide a very good user experience. And using HTML without javascript would render this project impossible.

Comment: Do you have any example using both HTML and Jquery?Or code.thanks

Comment: Sure: http://jsfiddle.net/Kzcur/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery and html5 are not alternatives, they can be used together. The example is done in flash, but I'm sure it can be done using a html5 canvas and javascript.